# Can you call a void function of array when it is in between two loops?

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I wrote code which take size of an array and enter the elements of an array and then cyclically rotate an array.
INPUT : 1 2 3 4 5 //elements of an array 
Correct Output: 5 1 2 3 4

//I made rotate function for the program but when i called it ,the program run but didnt show me the correct answer instead when i wrote that code in the main function like i've done below it worked out!!! WHY?

```
   #include<iostream>
   using namespace std;
   void rotate(int arr[],int n) 
   {                                
     int x=arr[n-1],i;
     for(i=n-1;i>0;i--)
     {arr[i]=arr[i-1];}
     arr[0]=arr[x];}
 int main()           
 {
  int t;
  cin>>t; //for test case(How many test cases i have to perform) 
  while(t--)
{
    int n,i,arr[i]; 
    cin>>n;  //size of an array 
    cout<<"Enter the given array :"<<endl;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {cin>>arr[i];}  //Enter elements of an array 
    cout<<"THe given array is :"<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) 
    {cout<<arr[i]<<" ";} //print the elements of an array
```

//Writing Whole ROTATE FUNCTION in the MAIN

```
    int x=arr[n-1],i; 
    for(i=n-1;i>0;i--)
    {arr[i]=arr[i-1];}
    arr[0]=arr[x];//when you didnt make  a function to rotate an array its compiled and  showing 
                 //correct results. why?    
    cout<<"The Rotated Array is :"<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {cout<<arr[i]<<" "; }
    cout<<endl;
}
```

}

When i called the rotate function in the main function it showed me following incorrect Output:
Output : 0 1 2 3 4.
FOllowing way the answer was incorrect:
    when i call :
         **rotate(arr,n)**
But When i didnt call a rotate function.Instead i wrote the whole function in the main,The output was corrected like i have shown you in the above code.

Comment: I don't see the call to your rotate function. Please show both versions of main. If there was a problem in how you were calling rotate, no one can help with that until they see what you did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
arr[0]=arr[x];
```

should be

```
arr[0]=x;
```

`arr[x]` is potentially an out of bounds array access, giving your programs undefined behaviour.